# What to do when one key needs to be pressed hard to register?

Tags: keyboard

I've a C.Y.B.O.R.G. v7 keyboard, and there's this one key that I need to press slightly harder than normal for it to register. It feels exactly the same as all of the other keys, and other than that, everything else works fine.

The strength required for it to register is *just* greater enough for it to not register during casual typing, but not too great that I feel like I might be damaging the keyboard.

I've tried:

- Removing the keycap and cleaning it with a moist piece of cloth.
- Installing the keyboard's drivers (because who knows).

What might cause this problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: You replace the keyboard.  If its a problem with the PCB then there isn't much that can be done without a circuit diagram and replacement parts and of course the skills required to make repairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely sounds to be a hardware issue.

If cleaning doesn't help, then replace it.